# C code to Assembly meaning of DWORD PTR a[rip]

Tags: assembly, x86-64, addressing-mode

I had an assigment to translate a C code to Assembly intel syntax x86.

```
int a;

void fg(){
   a=2;
}

int main(){
   fg();
   return a;
}
```

The result was this:

```
fg:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR a[rip], 2
        pop     rbp
        ret
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     eax, 0
        call    fg
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR a[rip]
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

Could someone explain to me how does the addressing of a global variable work?
And what does `a[rip]` means exactly?

Comment: Maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42215105/understanding-rip-register-in-intel-assembly

Comment: `a[rip]` means use position independent addressing to access `a`. The assembler/linker will figure out the distance from the current instruction pointer (rip) to `a` and use that offset.