# Storing strings in memory

Tags: c, assembly, memory

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    int i;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        puts("Hello world!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Which compiles into this:

```
   0x0000555555555149 <+0>:     endbr64 
   0x000055555555514d <+4>:     push   rbp
   0x000055555555514e <+5>:     mov    rbp,rsp
   0x0000555555555151 <+8>:     sub    rsp,0x10
   0x0000555555555155 <+12>:    mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x0
   0x000055555555515c <+19>:    jmp    0x555555555171 <main+40>
   0x000055555555515e <+21>:    lea    rax,[rip+0xe9f]        # 0x555555556004
   0x0000555555555165 <+28>:    mov    rdi,rax
   0x0000555555555168 <+31>:    call   0x555555555050 <puts@plt>
   0x000055555555516d <+36>:    add    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x1
   0x0000555555555171 <+40>:    cmp    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],0x9
   0x0000555555555175 <+44>:    jle    0x55555555515e <main+21>
   0x0000555555555177 <+46>:    mov    eax,0x0
   0x000055555555517c <+51>:    leave  
   0x000055555555517d <+52>:    ret
```

The string "Hello world!\n" must be located at [rip+0xe9f], but actualy at [rip+0xe9f] there are 7 extra characters in front of the line itself:

```
(gdb) x/20cb $rip+0xe9f                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
0x555555555ffd: 0 '\000'        0 '\000'        0 '\000'        1 '\001'        0 '\000'        2 '\002'        0 '\000'        72 'H'
0x555555556005: 101 'e' 108 'l' 108 'l' 111 'o' 32 ' '  119 'w' 111 'o' 114 'r'
0x55555555600d: 108 'l' 100 'd' 33 '!'  10 '\n'
```

But the comment points to the address where our string is actually located:

```
(gdb) x/s 0x555555556004                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
0x555555556004: "Hello world!\n"
```

Why is that?

Comment: Are you getting the value of `rip` at the right instruction in the assembly code? It is the instruction pointer after all, so the result of `rip+0xe9f` depends on the current instruction location.

Comment: Indeed, I was on one instruction before... Thx!

Answer (score 0):

rip is the instruction pointer, so the result of rip+0xe9f depends on the current instruction location. I was one instruction before.

Thanks to [Some programmer dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude)

Comment: `%rip` points at the *next* instruction, not the current one. For `lea    rax,[rip+0xe9f]` it is `0x0000555555555165 + 0xe9f = 0x555555556004`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42215105/understanding-rip-register-in-intel-assembly